# how to get access to my.ini or my.cnf (MySQL configuration) file of web hosting Godaddy

Tags: web, hosting

I have purchased web hosting from Go-daddy.com and i want to configure MySQL database using my.ini or my.cnf file. I am not finding any way to edit or access that file. Please suggest me option to get it done.

Comment: I'm having the same problem you find a solution in the end?

Comment: for which reason you want to access my.ini file. Because my problem was related with Full text Search char length and i have solved it with my own trick. If you have the same then tell me i will explain it..

Comment: didn't need to in the end, was just exploring all avenues!

Comment: I was/am screwed as it is now (first time ever) set to "strict" so every column has to have a default etc etc so stuff that was working is now F****D very annoying!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Debian **Linux** file is located at **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** location.
2. If you are using Red Hat **Linux/Fedora/Centos** Linux file is located at **/etc/my.cnflocation**.
3. If you are using **FreeBSD** you need to create a file **/var/db/mysql/my.cnf** location.